# How to make a radio button clickable but not checkable?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, clickable

`<input class="language-checkbox" name="languages-settings" disabled="true" type="radio" onclick="nonAvailable('englishLan');>`

This radio button is disabled. But I cannot use the onclick.

So I was wondering how I can make a radio-button uncheckable, but I can still use the onclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` inside the `onClick` function. as below:

```js
document.querySelector("#languages-settings").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log('I\'m unavailable.');
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<input class="language-checkbox" id="languages-settings" name="languages-settings" type="radio">
```